# QueryDatabaseTable error on AGGREGATE SQL functions

Tags: mysql, apache, apache-nifi

I want to perform average on few fields in the database table usingQueryDatabaseRecord processor. My query works fine in MySQL as follows:

```
select TimeOfDay,
    AVG(BMU_Debug_Pack_Blk_Volt_Delta), 
    AVG(BMU_Debug_Pack_CTemp_Min) 
from tt8;
```

All my fields are of "double" type" except TimeOfDay which is "varchar (10)". when I run Aggregate functions like AVG/Min etc on fields it gives me following error:

```
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: 
Error during database query or conversion of records to Avro
```

What is the correct way to write SQL query that allows me to perform aggregate function. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and add one of the queries that produces the error.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Thank you for your reply. The first query in the question which is calculating the  AVG  of specific field is what does not give me the output.

Comment: It is probably choking on the lack of a group by clause.  MySQL older versions allow for aggregate functions without a group by, while newer ones either deprecate or disallow it.  Add 'GROUP BY TimeOfDay, BMU_Debug_Pack_BlkVolt_Max2' and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Not enough information provided to diagnose the problem. If the first SELECT executing successfully, we'd expect other queries with aggregates to execute successfully.  If its the first query that's failing, then either add a `GROUP BY TimeOfDay` clause,  or wrap the `TimeOfDay` in the SELECT list in an aggregate function e.g. `MAX(TimeOfDay)`.   Or, remove `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` from sql_mode to re-enable the non-standard behavior of the MySQL extension to GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Alias` the aggregated columns in the custom query and try to execute again in NiFi, as processor outputs the data in avro format so we need to alias the aggregated columns to get the avro schema.

```
 select TimeOfDay,
        AVG(BMU_Debug_Pack_Blk_Volt_Delta) avg_BMU_Debug_Pack_Blk_Volt_Delta, 
        AVG(BMU_Debug_Pack_CTemp_Min) avg_BMU_Debug_Pack_CTemp_Min
 from tt8;
```

In Addition as you mentioned you are able to run the above query on mysql side **without** adding **group by clause** so,
If doesn't work then add all the non aggregated columns into `group by` clause and execute the query again

```
select TimeOfDay,
            AVG(BMU_Debug_Pack_Blk_Volt_Delta) avg_BMU_Debug_Pack_Blk_Volt_Delta, 
            AVG(BMU_Debug_Pack_CTemp_Min) avg_BMU_Debug_Pack_CTemp_Min
        from tt8
group by TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: Thank you it worked with alias and with group by as well.